# Autocomplete, multiple fields, PHP MySql

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm sure this is simple but driving me mad...

I have the following Autocomplete script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function lookup(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
} // lookup

function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
function fill2(thisValue) {
    $('#inputString2').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

Used with the following HTML:

```
<tr><td><input type="text" size="50" name=line1 value="" id="inputString"
onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" /><div class="suggestionsBox"
id="suggestions" style="display: none;"> <div class="suggestionList"
id="autoSuggestionsList">

                &nbsp;
</div><div></td><td>1<input type="radio" name="rank1" value="1" 
<? if ($rank1=="1"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >2
<input type="radio" name="rank1" value="2" 
<? if ($rank1=="2"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >3
<input type="radio" name="rank1" value="3"
<? if ($rank1=="3"){ echo "checked"; } ?> > 
4<input type="radio" name="rank1" value="4" <? if ($rank1=="4"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >
<tr><td><input type="text" size="50" name=line1 value="" id="inputString2"
onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill2();" />
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <img src="upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div></td><td>
1<input type="radio" name="rank2" value="1" <? if ($rank2=="1"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >
2<input type="radio" name="rank2" value="2" <? if ($rank2=="2"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >
3<input type="radio" name="rank2" value="3" <? if ($rank2=="3"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >
4<input type="radio" name="rank2" value="4" <? if ($rank2=="4"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >
```

If you look at the JS at the top I presumed that by making two functions assigning data to two fields with different IDs would allow me to have autocomplete on each field (which works ok) but when I make a choice it always popuklates the first text box, regardless of which input box I start from...meaning if i start typing in box 1(id inputString), then make a choice from the autocomplete suggestions, box 1 gets filled. But If I start typing in box 2(id inputString2) and get suggestions, click a suggestion, still box 1(id inputString) gets populated and not box 2(id inputString2).

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Darren

Comment: Could you post it to jFiddle? it would be easier to debug...

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

i have made it work without the selectorToUse trick.
The problem comes from you selectors in your post function.
Notice how i changed the lookup function (with "myInputString" class), and the selectors in the post function.
The way you called lookup function, you didnt have access to $(this).

I have also revorked the html tags so jquery can navigate them (use of .parent() function)

php file:

```
<?php
  die($_POST['queryString']);
?>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".myInputString").keyup(function() { // previous lookup function now anonymous
            var inputString = $(this).attr("value");
            var curTag = $(this);
            if(inputString.length == 0) {
                // Hide the suggestion box.
                $('#suggestions').hide();
            } else {
                $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                    if(data.length >0) {
                        curTag.parent().find('.suggestionsBox').show();
                        curTag.parent().find('.suggestionList').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
function fill2(thisValue) {
    $('#inputString2').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
</script>
```

and the form:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
        <input type="text" size="50" name=line1 value="" id="inputString" class="myInputString"  onblur="fill();" />
        <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                A
            </div>
            </div>
                &nbsp;
<?php $rank1 = 1;  $rank2 = 2; ?>
</td>
</tr>
1<input type="radio" name="rank1" value="1"
<?php if ($rank1=="1"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >2
<input type="radio" name="rank1" value="2"
<?php if ($rank1=="2"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >3
<input type="radio" name="rank1" value="3"
<?php if ($rank1=="3"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >
4<input type="radio" name="rank1" value="4" <? if ($rank1=="4"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >
<tr><td><input type="text" size="50" name=line1 value="" id="inputString2" class="myInputString"
 onblur="fill2();" />
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <img src="upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">B
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
1<input type="radio" name="rank2" value="1" <? if ($rank2=="1"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >
2<input type="radio" name="rank2" value="2" <? if ($rank2=="2"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >
3<input type="radio" name="rank2" value="3" <? if ($rank2=="3"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >
4<input type="radio" name="rank2" value="4" <? if ($rank2=="4"){ echo "checked"; } ?> >
```

Comment: Have copied what you say verbatim but doesn't work...in fact crashes all html formatting, not sure if i'm copying wrong but can't see how

Comment: Also, you say:php file:

<?php
  die($_POST['queryString']);
?>

Comment: If you think you can really solve i'm happy to send files to you to amend if you have the time to try test and correct?

Comment: Yea i'd be glad to do so, but add an email to your profile so i can talk directly to you. And later i will rework my answer to be more usefull to others.

Answer (score 0):

from http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/:

> Each id value must be used only once
>   within a document. If more than one
>   element has been assigned the same ID,
>   queries that use that ID will only
>   select the first matched element in
>   the DOM. This behavior should not be
>   relied on, however; a document with
>   more than one element using the same
>   ID is invalid.

The reason why you are having your problem is because you have two ids with the same id:

```
id=autoSuggestionsList
```

I suggest that you change them to `autoSuggestionsList1` and `autoSuggestionsList2` and then change your function:

```
function lookup(inputString, selectorToUse) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#'+selectorToUse).html(data);
            }
        });
    }
} // lookup
```

and then change `lookup(this.value)`

to `lookup(this.value, "autoSuggestionsList1")` and `lookup(this.value, "autoSuggestionsList2")`.

Hope that helps! Please mark as answer if it did.